# QR code comparison to string ANDROID

Tags: android, qr-code

I'm using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0' (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/Barcode.html#valueFormat) to read QR code. I want to be compare my read QR to a String. If it matches, it should display a message.

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            final Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
            // I also tried barcode.displayValue!
            final String password = barcode.rawValue;

            if (password == "123456") {
                resultText.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        resultText.setText("Sucess");
                    }
                });
```

When I display my QR code, it reads 123456, but comparing it to "123456" doesn't work.

I thought displayValue and rawValue were casting my QR into a string. Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use `password.equals("123456")` to compare your strings. the `==` operator checks to see if the strings are the exact same object instead of having the same value.

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            final Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
            // I also tried barcode.displayValue!
            final String password = barcode.rawValue;

            if (password.equals("123456")) {
                resultText.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        resultText.setText("Sucess");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It was simple, but well explained. =] It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use equals it will return true if they are equal otherwise return false for [details](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html)

```
password.equals("12345")
```

Answer (score 1):

use password.equals("123456"), which is valid for comparing strings. I hope this will resolve your problem. As "==" compares the reference of the value in strings, where as .equals() compare the actual value .